# Bash throwing error continously which cannot be canceled with CTRL + C

Tags: linux, bash, termux, ps1

I was playing with PS1 variable to decorate my terminal but suddenly this happened.
[image: error]

It is continously throwing `bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'`. I tried `CTRL + C` and `CTRL + D` but nothing worked.

This code is from `~/.bahsrc` file so it gets executed as soon as I open the terminal. Is there any way to fix this without clearing data of Termux?

If I need to clear data Termux, is there any way to backup the HOME Directory of Termux?

Comment: Can you run any other shell than bash?

Comment: No. Because when I open the app the code automatically starts executing and throwing error

Comment: I have never worked with `termux`, but I bet that this application can be configured, with which command your shell is started. You could configure it to run a bash with the command `bash --norc`, and this would bypass your .bashrc. You then have a working shell from which you can easily debug your .bashrc. The problem of how tor run termux with a shell of your liking, is however a question which should be asked at [su] instead of stackoverflow, because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hold the Termux icon, it should display a menu that makes it possible to run "Failsafe". There, you can `mv .bashrc .bashrc.bad` (or `.profile` or whatever causes the problem) and then run a normal session.